# How to make a basic progress bar in python 3.5.0

Tags: progress-bar, task, percentage

```js
import time
for b in range(3):
    print('loading', end='')
    for a in range(3):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('.', end='')
    for x in range(100):
        print("")
```

We tried this but it did not work, and looks a bit untidy, any suggestions that work would be greatly appreciated.